# Getting a solution while accessing oracle database from .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle10g

I have a C# program that uses System.Data.OracleClient to access an oracle database.

The code uses OracleCommand, Dataset objects.

The command structure as below

```
con = new OracleConnection(conStr);
con.Open();
OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter("select * from sample", con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(ds);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
con.Close();
```

and the initialize value as

```
 public static String conStr = "SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=******)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=******)));uid=#####;pwd=#######;";
private OracleConnection con;
private String query;
private OracleCommand cmd;
private OracleDataReader rd;
```

and

i am getting error as

Stack Trace:

```
  at System.Data.OracleClient.OciHandle..ctor(OciHandle parentHandle, HTYPE handleType, MODE ocimode, HANDLEFLAG handleflags)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection.OpenOnLocalTransaction(String userName, String password, String serverName, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean unicode, Boolean omitOracleConnectionName)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection..ctor(OracleConnectionString connectionOptions)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open()
   at oracleTest.Program.showdata() in D:\oracle\oracletst[via-oracleclient]\oracletst\Program.cs:line 43
   at oracleTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\oracle\oracletst[via-oracleclient]\oracletst\Program.cs:line 22
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Target Site:

```
{Void .ctor(System.Data.OracleClient.OciHandle, HTYPE, MODE, HANDLEFLAG)}
```

Message :

```
OCIEnvCreate failed with return code -1 but error message text was not available.
```

I do not know where do i got stuck in.

i am using oracle 10g and dotnet 2010.

Waiting for your valuable responses and comments......

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://oraclepoint.com/oralife/2010/08/19/oracle-odbc-connection-issue-of-system-exception-ocienvcreate-failed-with-return-code-1-on-windows-with-asp/